# xslt format-number difference between #,###.00 and ###,###.00

Tags: xslt

Can anybody tell me the difference between these two ways of formatting numbers using format-number in xslt?

## ,###.00 vs ###,###.00

They seem to give the same result.

```
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(1000000, "###,###.00")' />
<xsl:value-of select='format-number(1000000, "#,###.00")' />
```

I get the same result of 1,000,000.00 in either case.  What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after reading the manual carefully, i have found there is no difference at all. since by comma(,), it indicates, it's the thousand seperator and both be the same.

http://www.w3schools.com/XSL/func_formatnumber.asp

Comment: So how would they each display, for example, 1000 differently?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. after reading the manual carefully, i have found there is no difference at all. since by comma(,), it indicates, it's the thousand seperator and both be the same.